# How to efficiently index fields with an identical (and long) prefix in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

I’m working with identifiers in a rather unusual format: every single ID has the same prefix and the prefix consists of as many as 25 characters. The only thing that is unique is the last part of the ID string and it has a variable length of up to ten characters:

```
ID
----------------------------------
lorem:ipsum:dolor:sit:amet:12345
lorem:ipsum:dolor:sit:amet:abcd123
lorem:ipsum:dolor:sit:amet:efg1
```

I’m looking for advice on the best strategy around indexing and matching this kind of ID string in PostgreSQL.

One approach I have considered is basically cutting these long prefixes out and only storing the unique suffix in the table column.

Another option that comes to mind is only indexing the suffix:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON books (substring(book_id FROM 26));
```

I don’t think this is the best idea though as you would need to remember to always strip out the prefix when querying the table. If you forgot to do it and had a `WHERE book_id = '<full ID here>'` filter, the index would basically be ignored by the planner.

Comment: Just store and index the full identifier, prefix and all. Ask yourself: what maintenance issue will I have when a second prefix comes along?  What happens when the suffix is no longer unique due to the additional prefix?

Comment: Right. Consider how bad it would be to lose 50 bytes per row (with the index). If it is bad enough, omit the constant prefix (your first approach).

Comment: In terms of performance it makes very little difference if you are indexing the whole ID or if you are skipping the first 25 characters. In terms of index size it could make a difference but I don't think it will be [very] significant.

Comment: If you always query for the full ID, then index the full ID. If you always query for only the unique part, then store only the unique part and create a generated column that adds the constant prefix or use a view to add that prefix (that you don't need to store it redundantly)

Comment: Huge thanks for your suggestions, guys. I really like the idea of a generated column, @a_horse_with_no_name but I thought of doing it the other way around: store the full ID in a column and have a generated one that only holds the actual ID part. To my surprise, Postgres even allows you to declare that generated column as `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

Most times I always create an integer type `ID` for my tables if even I have one unique string type of field. Recommendation for you is a good idea, I must view all your queries in DB. If you are recently using `substring(book_id FROM 26)` after the `where` statement, this is the best way to create `expression index` (function-based index). Basically, you need to check table joining conditions, which fields are used in the joining processes, and which fields are used after `WHERE` statements in your queries. After then you can prepare the best plan for creating indexes. If on the process of table joining you are using last part unique characters on the `ID` field then this is the best way to extract unique last characters and store this in additional fields or create expression index using the function for extracting unique characters.